# Capture repeating, comma-separated strings in regex

Tags: java, regex, backreference

I have a requirement to capture multiple phrases available in a line (or a input string).
Let's say input is = "this is description,this is description" 
So I need to detect the string "this is description" has repeated twice in the input.

This is the regex I've tried so far

```
(.*).*\1
```

But it matches input that doesn't have exact repetitions like "this is description,more text,this is description"

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Why isn't it working? It [is](https://regex101.com/r/6gCwbt/1).

Comment: The regex will tell you in the pattern appears in the string. In your example, you have artificially declared 2 phrases in one string. How is your code supposed to know that? You should first separate the different phrases into their own strings, and then test each string by itself.

Answer (score 0):

To find repeating *pairs* of comma-separated strings:

```
(.+?),\1
```

To find any number of repeating values (comma-separated):

```
(.+?)(?:,\1)+
```

These work by doing a non-greedy match up to the first comma and then a repeat after the comma.

Comment: Thanks, but these are capturing this as well which my requirement dont want like "this is test,this is not test"